# How to fix unpacking of response from server error AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'tag'

Tags: python, sockets, struct

I'm receiving a response from a network server and attempting to unpack the response and the display it out on the screen, but came across the error

```
 AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'tag'
```

I think it maybe do to how I am calling the variables above. Please dont forget I am super new to python and socket programming.

Anyway the response format has 3 parts to it

```
       TYPE  OFFSET
 tag   uint32    0
 code  uint32    4
 message string  8
```

Expected to display: Tag: 1(or anynumber)
                     Code: 200(success)
                     Message: 'hey'

```
            import socket
            import struct
            import textwrap

            TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
            TCP_PORT = 4200

            TAB_1 = '\t - '
            TAB_2 = '\t\t - '
            TAB_3 = '\t\t\t - '
            TAB_4 = '\t\t\t\t - '

            DATA_TAB_1 = '\t   '
            DATA_TAB_2 = '\t\t   '
            DATA_TAB_3 = '\t\t\t   '
            DATA_TAB_4 = '\t\t\t\t   '

            def main():
                s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                s.connect(("127.0.0.1", 4200))

                packet = struct.pack('ii', 1,4)

                s.send(packet)

                while True:
                    response, addr = s.recvfrom(65535)
                    print(response.__sizeof__())
                    bny = binary_response(response)
                    print(TAB_1 + 'Binary Response Segment:')
                    print(TAB_2 + 'Tag: {}, Code: {}' + bny.tag, bny.code)
                    print(TAB_2 + 'Message: ' + bny.response)


            # Unpack binary_response
            def binary_response(response):
                tag, code = struct.unpack('i i', response[:12])
                return tag, code, response[12:]




            main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says, `binary_response()` returns a tuple, but you're trying to access the returned tag value as though it were an attribute.  It isn't.

Since tag is the first element in the returned tuple, use `bny[0]` instead of `bny.tag`.

Comment: This did fix my issue with that error and now I am having 2 values showing on the screen. Now just got to figure out where to start this data because I’m getting 2  0s back. But that’s a separate question